# Remove Borders around a QLabel in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4

I have added one qlabel in my application's statusbar . And now I have been trying to remove the borders around the QLabel.

```
label->setFrameShape(QFrame::HLine);
label->setFrameStyle(QFrame::NoFrame);
// label->setLineWidth(0);
//label->setMidLineWidth(0);
```

I tried everything above, none of them work, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can do this with style sheets. Where you declare your `QApplication app` variable add underneath a line like this:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
app.setStyleSheet("QStatusBar::item { border: 0px solid black }; ");
```

and those pesky boxes will be gone.